# Create a link to open a Microsoft Teams chat to a specific person

Tags: html, hyperlink, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to embed html code on a page that provides a link, that when clicked, opens a chat window with a specific user.  I've tried the following code, but when clicked Teams opens and tries to get me to login again.  I never get the chat window.  Thoughts?

```
<a href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users="username@userdomain.com" 'target='_blank'</a>

<a href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=username@userdomain.com 'target='_blank'</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

both of your links are invalid. One of the following should work:

```
<a href='https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users="username@userdomain.com"' target="_blank">username@userdomain.com</a>

<a href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=username@userdomain.com" target="_blank">username@userdomain.com</a>
```

Comment: The web version of Teams tried to open, then the app popped up and asked me to login, even though I was already logged in.  I didn't get a window with the direct chat to the other person that I wanted.